# Why doesn't click event always fire?

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js

*If you're revisiting this question I've moved all the updates to the bottom so it actually reads better as a question.*

### The Problem

I've got a bit of a strange problem handling browser events using `D3`. Unfortunately this sits in quite a large application, and because I'm completely lost on what the cause is I'm struggling to find a small reproduceable example so I'm going to provide as much hopefully useful information as I can.

So my problem is that `click` events don't seem to fire reliably for certain DOM Elements. I have two different sets of elements **Filled** circles and **White** circles. You can see in the screenshot below *1002* and *1003* are white circles, while *Suppliers* is a filled circle.

[image]

Now this problem **only** occurs for the white circles which I don't understand. The screenshot below shows what happens when I click the circles. The order of clicks is shown via the red numbers, and the logging associated with them. Essentially what you see is:

- mousedown
- mouseup
- sometimes a click

The issue is a bit sporadic. I had managed to track down a realiable reproduction but after a few refreshes of the browser it's now much harder to reproduce. If I alternate click on *1002* and *1003* then I keep getting `mousedown` and `mouseup` events but never a `click`. If I click on one of them a second time then I do get a `click` event. If I keep clicking on the same one (not shown here) only every other click fires the `click` event.

If I repeat the same process with a filled circle like *Suppliers* then it works fine and `click` is fired every single time.

---

### How the Circles are created

So the circles (aka Planets in my code) have been created as a modular component. There for the data is looped through and an instance for each is created

```
data.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", function (d) { return d.promoted ? "collection moon-group" : "collection planet-group"; })
    .call(drag)
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        var scale = d.size / 150;
        return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ") scale(" + [scale] + ")";
    })
    .each(function (d) {

        // Create a new planet for each item
        d.planet = new d3.landscape.Planet()
                              .data(d, function () { return d.id; })
                              .append(this, d);
    });
```

This doesn't tell you all that much, underneath a `Force Directed` graph is being used to calculate positions. The code within the `Planet.append()` function is as follows:

```
d3.landscape.Planet.prototype.append = function (target) {
    var self = this;

    // Store the target for later
    self.__container = target;
    self.__events = new custom.d3.Events("planet")
                                    .on("click", function (d) { self.__setSelection(d, !d.selected); })
                                    .on("dblclick", function (d) { self.__setFocus(d, !d.focused); self.__setSelection(d, d.focused); });

    // Add the circles
    var circles = d3.select(target)
                    .append("circle")
                    .attr("data-name", function (d) { return d.name; })
                    .attr("class", function(d) { return d.promoted ? "moon" : "planet"; })
                    .attr("r", function () { return self.__animate ? 0 : self.__planetSize; })
                    .call(self.__events);
```

Here we can see the circles being appended (note each Planet is actually just a single circle). The custom.d3.Events is constructed and called for the circle that has just been added to the DOM. This code is used for both the filled and the white circles, the only difference is a slight variation in the classes. The DOM produced for each looks like:

#### Filled

```html
<g class="collection planet-group" transform="translate(683.080338895066,497.948470463691) scale(0.6666666666666666,0.6666666666666666)">   
  <circle data-name="Suppliers" class="planet" r="150"></circle>
  <text class="title" dy=".35em" style="font-size: 63.1578947368421px;">Suppliers</text>   
</g>
```

#### White

```html
<g class="collection moon-group" transform="translate(679.5720546510213,92.00957926233855) scale(0.6666666666666666,0.6666666666666666)">      
  <circle data-name="1002" class="moon" r="150"></circle>   
  <text class="title" dy=".35em" style="font-size: 75px;">1002</text>
</g>
```

---

### What does custom.d3.events do?

The idea behind this is to provide a richer event system than you get by default. For example allowing double-clicks (that don't trigger single clicks) and long clicks etc.

When events is called with the `circle` container is executes the following, setting up some `raw` events using D3. These aren't the same ones that have been hooked up to in the `Planet.append()` function, because the `events` object exposes it's own custom dispatch. These are the events however that I'm using for debugging/logging;

```
custom.d3.Events = function () {

   var dispatch = d3.dispatch("click", "dblclick", "longclick", "mousedown", "mouseup", "mouseenter", "mouseleave", "mousemove", "drag");

   var events = function(g) {
       container = g;

       // Register the raw events required
       g.on("mousedown", mousedown)
        .on("mouseenter", mouseenter)
        .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
        .on("click", clicked)
        .on("contextmenu", contextMenu)
        .on("dblclick", doubleClicked);

       return events;
   };

   // Return the bound events
   return d3.rebind(events, dispatch, "on");
}
```

So in here, I hook up to a few events. Looking at them in reverse order:

#### click

The click function is set to simply log the value that we're dealing with

```
 function clicked(d, i) {
    console.log("clicked", d3.event.srcElement);
    // don't really care what comes after
 }
```

#### mouseup

The mouseup function essentially logs, and clear up some global window objects, that will be discussed next.

```
 function mouseup(d, i) {
    console.log("mouseup", d3.event.srcElement);
    dispose_window_events();
 }
```

#### mousedown

The mousedown function is a little more complex and I'll include the entirety of it. It does a number of things:

- Logs the mousedown to console
- Sets up window events (wires up mousemove/mouseup on the window object) so mouseup can be fired even if the mouse is no longer within the circle that triggered mousedown
- Finds the mouse position and calculates some thresholds
- Sets up a timer to trigger a long click
- Fires the mousedown dispatch that lives on the custom.d3.event object

  ```
  function mousedown(d, i) {
     console.log("mousedown", d3.event.srcElement);

     var context = this;
     dragging = true;
     mouseDown = true;

     // Wire up events on the window
     setup_window_events();

     // Record the initial position of the mouse down
     windowStartPosition = getWindowPosition();
     position = getPosition();

     // If two clicks happened far apart (but possibly quickly) then suppress the double click behaviour
     if (windowStartPosition && windowPosition) {
         var distance = mood.math.distanceBetween(windowPosition.x, windowPosition.y, windowStartPosition.x, windowStartPosition.y);
         supressDoubleClick = distance > moveThreshold;
     }
     windowPosition = windowStartPosition;

     // Set up the long press timer only if it has been subscribed to - because
     // we don't want to suppress normal clicks otherwise.
     if (events.on("longclick")) {
         longTimer = setTimeout(function () {
             longTimer = null;
             supressClick = true;
             dragging = false;
             dispatch.longclick.call(context, d, i, position);
         }, longClickTimeout);
     }

     // Trigger a mouse down event
     dispatch.mousedown.call(context, d, i);
     if(debug) { console.log(name + ": mousedown"); }
  }
  ```

---

**Update 1**

I should add that I have experienced this in Chrome, IE11 and Firefox (although this seems to be the most reliable of the browsers).

Unfortunately after some refresh and code change/revert I've struggled getting the reliable reproduction. What I have noticed however which is odd is that the following sequence can produce different results:

- F5 Refresh the Browser
- Click on `1002`

Sometimes this triggeres `mousedown`, `mouseup` and then `click`. Othertimes it misses off the `click`. It seems quite strange that this issue can occur sporadically between two different loads of the same page.

I should also add that I've tried the following:

- Caused `mousedown` to fail and verify that `click` still fires, to ensure a sporadic error in `mousedown` could not be causing the problem. I can confirm that `click` will fire event if there is an error in `mousedown`.
- Tried to check for timing issues. I did this by inserting a long blocking loop in `mousedown` and can confirm that the `mouseup` and `click` events will fire after a considerable delay. So the events do look to be executing sequentially as you'd expect.

---

**Update 2**

A quick update after @CoolBlue's comment is that adding a namespace to my event handlers doesn't seem to make any difference. The following still experiences the problem sporadically:

```
var events = function(g) {
    container = g;

    // Register the raw events required
    g.on("mousedown.test", mousedown)
     .on("mouseenter.test", mouseenter)
     .on("mouseleave.test", mouseleave)
     .on("click.test", clicked)
     .on("contextmenu.test", contextMenu)
     .on("dblclick.test", doubleClicked);

    return events;
};
```

Also the `css` is something that I've not mentioned yet. The css should be similar between the two different types. The complete set is shown below, in particular the `point-events` are set to `none` just for the label in the middle of the circle. I've taken care to avoid clicking on that for some of my tests though and it doesn't seem to make much difference as far as I can tell.

```
/* Mixins */
/* Comment here */
.collection .planet {
  fill: #8bc34a;
  stroke: #ffffff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 0;
  transition: stroke-width 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-width 0.25s;
}
.collection .title {
  fill: #ffffff;
  text-anchor: middle;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.collection.related .planet {
  stroke-width: 10px;
}
.collection.focused .planet {
  stroke-width: 22px;
}
.collection.selected .planet {
  stroke-width: 22px;
}

.moon {
  fill: #ffffff;
  stroke: #8bc34a;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
.moon-container .moon {
  transition: stroke-width 1s;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-width 1s;
}
.moon-container .moon:hover circle {
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
.moon-container text {
  fill: #8bc34a;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
.collection.moon-group .title {
  fill: #8bc34a;
  text-anchor: middle;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.collection.moon-group .moon {
  stroke-width: 3px;
  transition: stroke-width 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-width 0.25s;
}
.collection.moon-group.related .moon {
  stroke-width: 10px;
}
.collection.moon-group.focused .moon {
  stroke-width: 22px;
}
.collection.moon-group.selected .moon {
  stroke-width: 22px;
}
.moon:hover {
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

---

**Update 3**

So I've tried ruling different things out. One is to change the CSS such that the `white` circles *1002* and *1003* now use the same class and therefore same CSS as *Suppliers* which is the one that worked. You can see the image and CSS below as proof:

[image]

```html
<g class="collection planet-group" transform="translate(1132.9999823040162,517.9999865702812) scale(0.6666666666666666,0.6666666666666666)">
   <circle data-name="1003" class="planet" r="150"></circle>
   <text class="title" dy=".35em" style="font-size: 75px;">1003</text>
</g>
```

I also decided to modify the `custom.d3.event` code as this is the most complex bit of eventing. I stripped it right back down to simply just logging:

```
var events = function(g) {
    container = g;

    // Register the raw events required
    g.on("mousedown.test", function (d) { console.log("mousedown.test"); })
     .on("click.test", function (d) { console.log("click.test"); });

    return events;
};
```

Now it seems that this still didn't solve the problem. Below is a trace (now I'm not sure why I get two click.test events fired each time - appreciate if anyone can explain it... but for now taking that as the norm). What you can see is that on the ocassion highlighted, the `click.test` did not get logged, I had to click again - hence the double `mousedown.test` before the click was registered.

[image]

---

**Update 4**

So after a suggestion from @CoolBlue I tried looking into the `d3.behavior.drag` that I've got set up. I've tried removing the wireup of the drag behaviour and I can't see any issues after doing so - which could indicate a problem in there. This is designed to allow the circles to be dragged within a force directed graph. So I've added some logging in the drag so I can keep an eye on whats going on:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
             .on("dragstart", function () { console.log("dragstart"); self.__dragstart(); })
             .on("drag", function (d, x, y) { console.log("drag", d3.event.sourceEvent.x, d3.event.sourceEvent.y); self.__drag(d); })
             .on("dragend", function (d) { console.log("dragend"); self.__dragend(d); });
```

I was also pointed to the `d3` code base for the [drag event](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/event/drag.js) which has a `suppressClick` flag in there. So I modified this slightly to see if this was suppressing the click that I was expecting.

```
return function (suppressClick) {
     console.log("supressClick = ", suppressClick);
     w.on(name, null);
     ...
}
```

The results of this were a bit strange. I've merged all the logging together to illustrate 4 different examples:

- Blue: The click fired correctly, I noted that `suppressClick` was false.
- Red: The click didn't fire, it looks like I'd accidentally triggered a move but `suppressClick` was still false.
- Yellow: The click did fire, `suppressClick` was still false but there was an accidental move. I don't know why this differs from the previous red one.
- Green: I deliberately moved slightly when clicking, this set `suppressClick` to true and the click didn't fire.

[image]

---

**Update 5**

So looking in depth at the `D3` code a bit more, I really can't explain the inconsistencies that I see in the behavior that I detailed in update 4. I just tried something different on the off-chance to see if it did what I expected. Basically I'm forcing `D3` to **never** suppress the click. So in the [drag event](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/event/drag.js)

```
return function (suppressClick) {
    console.log("supressClick = ", suppressClick);
    suppressClick = false;
    w.on(name, null);
    ...
}
```

After doing this I still managed to get a fail, which raises questions as to whether it really is the suppressClick flag that is causing it. This might also explain the inconsistencies in the console via update #4. I also tried upping the `setTimeout(off, 0)` in there and this didn't prevent *all* of the clicks from firing like I'd expect.

So I believe this suggests maybe the `suppressClick` isn't actually the problem. Here's a console log as proof (and I also had a colleague double check to ensure that I'm not missing anything here):

[image]

---

**Update 6**

I've found another bit of code that may well be relevant to this problem (but I'm not 100% sure). Where I hook up to the `d3.behavior.drag` I use the following:

```
 var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
             .on("dragstart", function () { self.__dragstart(); })
             .on("drag", function (d) { self.__drag(d); })
             .on("dragend", function (d) { self.__dragend(d); });
```

So I've just been looking into the `self.__dragstart()` function and noticed a `d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();`. There isn't much more in these functions (generally just starting/stopping the force directed graph and updating positions of lines).

I'm wondering if this could be influencing the click behavior. If I take this `stopPropagation` out then my whole surface begins to pan, which isn't desirable so that's probably not the answer, but could be another avenue to investigate.

---

**Update 7**

One possible glaring emissions that I forgot to add to the original question. The visualization also supports zooming/panning.

```
 self.__zoom = d3.behavior
                        .zoom()
                        .scaleExtent([minZoom, maxZoom])
                        .on("zoom", function () { self.__zoomed(d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale); });
```

Now to implement this there is actually a large rectangle over the top of everything. So my top level `svg` actually looks like:

```html
<svg class="galaxy">
   <g width="1080" height="1795">
      <rect class="zoom" width="1080" height="1795" style="fill: none; pointer-events: all;"></rect>
   <g class="galaxy-background" width="1080" height="1795" transform="translate(-4,21)scale(1)"></g>
   <g class="galaxy-main" width="1080" height="1795" transform="translate(-4,21)scale(1)">
   ... all the circles are within here
   </g>
</svg>
```

I remembered this when I turned off the `d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();` in the callback for the `drag` event on `d3.behaviour.drag`. This stopped any click events getting through to my circles which confused me somewhat, then I remembered the large rectangle when inspecting the DOM. I'm not quite sure why re-enabling the propagation prevents the click at the moment.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried name-spacing the various events, like, for example `.on("click.planet", function (d) {`?

Comment: @CoolBlue: I haven't, though I've never had any success with namespaces. Modifying the registrations in custom.d3.events to things like ` g.on("test.mousedown", mousedown)` seems to stop them getting fired at all. I don't get any logging etc.

Comment: That should be `g.on("mousedown.test", mousedown)` ... also whats going on with your CSS, particularly regarding `pointer-events`?

Comment: There is also funny business going on with `behaviour.drag`, it might be worth sniffing around in there as well.  It puts a listener on `mousedown` there.  Is it `behaviour.drag()` or `force.drag()`?

Comment: @CoolBlue: Added an update regarding you're previous comment. That's true regarding the .drag() - hadn't thought of that. It's a regular `d3.behaviour.drag()` that I'm using there. I'll try and do some more digging on that, it's getting a bit tricky with my reproduction not being so reliable at the moment so may take a little while.

Comment: I would definitely poke some logs in the `behaviour.drag` listeners to see what's going on there.  Also, your pointer-events is passive, what if you try `.planet { pointer-events: all; }`?

Comment: @CoolBlue : https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior can't listen to any other events as there aren't any (unless I modify D3 code internally). Can confirm that the `point-event: all` doesn't change the state of play. Interesting thing to look at though, as `css` is about the only thing different between the two. However if I modify the classes of a `white` circle to match the `filled` then that doesn't fix anything though. Which I guess raises questions on if it is css.

Comment: Yes, you need to modify your local copy of d3, that's the best way to get traction on it.  I got interested in CSS coz `pointer-events: auto` leaves un-filled shapes transparent to mouse events (unless you snag the stroke), so the main difference is filled vs not filled and how that interacts with the CSS.  What happens if you fill the white circles?

Comment: Probably the most fertile area though is your de-bouncing timers in your custom click behaviour.  It looks like a state machine problem.

Comment: @CoolBlue ok, I've ruled out the css... I just tried switching to the use the same class, so now `filled` and `white` use exactly the same styles, but the issue remains. Also the `white` actually has a white fill so was never transparent. I don't believe I'm actually de-bouncing at this point, but I'll try stripping out the events as much as possible to see if I can reduce the problem area a bit more and post back here.

Comment: @CoolBlue: Oddly, changing the events wire up to `g.on("click.test", function (d) { console.log("click.test"); } )` seems to always log `click.test` twice after the `mousedown`, `mouseup` pair. That doesn't seem right? If I put revert to my function however which has `console.log` right at the top, I only get 1 console entry...

Comment: I would still try a darker colour in case the browser is playing games with white being the same as background.  And sorry, just my old-fashioned terminology, I mean the state machine created by the timers in your `mousedown` function.  It's reasonably likely that the problem is in there.

Comment: Maybe that's a clue mate, it means the namespacing is differentiating _your_ click from another one.  It means that without the NS your click is being cross-wired.

Comment: @CoolBlue - I've added an update to the question, stripping out all my custom logic from the events, using exactly the same CSS as the ones that seem to work to no avail. I'm going to focus on double checking that this isn't affecting the `filled` or Supplier circle and then look at debugging the `d3.behaviour.drag` to see if that reveals more. Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: This would be interesting to understand: `dispose_window_events();`  Regarding the double reports, its probably to do with bubbling between the circle and the `g`, I would be a bit more verbose in your console logs: I would log `target` and `currentTarget`... that will probably differentiate the two clicks.  Might be worth enabling show timestamps in the console section of the browser tools settings as well?

Comment: @CoolBlue: you're correct in the events bubbling. The 2nd click `currentTarget` is indeed the `g` element. `dispose_window_events()` really isn't that interesting, and currently isn't being used after stripping that event wire-up down. But it was just: `d3.select(window).on("mousemove", null).on("mouseup", null);`

Comment: Ahh, of course: OK. For a minute I thought it might be affecting propagation, hence my interest.  Did you try removing the drag behaviour by the way?

Comment: @CoolBlue: Not yet, about to start looking at that. Gotta get a large check-in done first now I've realised this is an existing bug!

Comment: @CoolBlue: I'm not having much success modifying `d3` unfortunately, generally speaking get a `Cannot read property 'on' of undefined` when I try. Removing the `drag` however I notice that I start receiving 2 `mousedown.test` followed by 2 `click.test` so it feels like the problem might be in there somewhere.

Comment: Yes, this is in the dragStart routine: `dragRestore = d3_event_dragSuppress(target),` it's calling a function in the event drag module and in that routine is this line: `if (suppressClick) { // suppress the next click, but only if it’s immediate`, I find the code around the drag behaviour very difficult to read coz the higher order functions make me car sick, but I suspect the problem is related to that.  It gets worse for force drag... Maybe it's an edge case? Does it only happen when clicking quite rappidly?

Comment: [d3/src/behaviour/drag](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/behavior/drag.js). [d3/src/event/drag](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/event/drag.js).

Comment: @CoolBlue: No, it can happen with quite slow clicks. When I originally posted it occurred clicking 1 circle, then the other, then clicking on the first again. If I didn't click a circle twice I could reliably get `mousedown` events with no `click` events at that point in time.

Comment: @CoolBlue: I've added another update (now at the bottom of the post). Looks like drag is the issue, but it's behaving oddly. Clicks sometimes don't work despite suppressClick being false

Comment: It seems to me that the root cause of the problem is that you have different event handlers for essentially the same thing -- your custom handlers for the circles and the drag behaviour for the the `g` elements that contain them. I would try to handle *everything* in a single set of handlers, otherwise completely unrelated changes like changing the CSS from white/transparent to another colour could break things.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: I did start considering that yesterday. The only downside is I feel like I'll be losing any useful logic that already resides in the D3 drag behavior, but at this point I'm not sure there's a better option. I would quite like to understand the why however if I can, as I had considered making the custom events a reusable D3 component.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: I also thought that the whole purpose of namespacing events in `d3` was to allow you to do this

Comment: @Ian Yes, but that's for events on the same element. I *think* the problem in your case is that sometimes one element gets the event, sometimes the other, sometimes both (at least that what it sounds like to me). There's nothing you can really do with namespaces there.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Yeah I guess that is one option, trying to track down which elements are responding to the events is I guess the next stage. I had a quick go at using my own events code to implement drag and unfortunately it fell flat on its face. I may go back to that approach soon if I can't find a resolution to this.

Comment: You could also just copy the source of the D3 drag behaviour and modify that as necessary.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I could, if I actually knew which bit was causing the problem

Comment: What I mean is that you could reimplement your custom behaviour this way and then have only a single event handler that does it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently came across this again, and fortunately have managed to isolate the problem and work around it.

It was actually due to something being registered in the `mousedown` event, which was moving the DOM element `svg:circle` to the top based on a z-order. It does this by taking it out the DOM and re-inserting it at the appropriate place.

This produces something that flows like this:

- mouseenter
- mousedown

  - (move DOM element but keep same event wrapper)
  - mouseup

The problem is, as far as the browser is concerned the `mousedown` and `mouseup` occurred almost on different elements in the DOM, moving it has messed up the event model.

Therefore in my case I've applied a fix by firing the `click` event manually on `mouseup` if the original `mousedown` occured within the same element.

Comment: `mouseup` of same element is not getting executed in my case. Are you telling you are dispatching click event on `mouseup` event of  some other element in DOM ? (which is getting executed instead).

Answer (score 1):

```
var events = function(g) {

    // Register the raw events required
    g.on("mousedown.test", mousedown)
     .on("mouseenter.test", mouseenter)
     .on("mouseleave.test", mouseleave)
     .on("click.test", clicked)
     .on("contextmenu.test", contextMenu)
     .on("dblclick.test", doubleClicked);

    return g;
};
```

Returning g instead of events might resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and this is actually probably a mistake not returning `g` in the first place but unfortunately doesn't seem to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be with the rectangle layer too or with the way you call your event suppressor. It may simply cause your keyup event to hang instead of being cancelled so your first key up event returns after the second click. You should implement a counter on your events to verify this theory and return the value of the counter with the event name in the log.