# d3 drag and drop mouse click event not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, drag-and-drop

I am working on the d3 drag and drop functionality ,i followed the link

> http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

for the d3 drag and drop functionality , it working perfectly as per the d3 v3 version example but i want to do d3 v4 so i looked on the master changes in 
as per the d3 master changes

> https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md

I converted all the changes everything working fine , except the mouse click and double click event, so i gone through the issue in the d3 forum  i find out some solution on that

> [Why doesn't click event always fire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243959/why-doesnt-click-event-always-fire)

But still that was open issue or closed ,Could you anyone know how to solve that issue let me know , share the links.Thanks.

```
var nodeEnter =  node.enter().append('g').call(d3.drag()                                     
                                .on("start", dragstarted)
                                .on("drag", dragged)
                                .on("end", dragended)).on("click",collapse)
                              .on("mouseover", overCircle)                                
                             .on("mouseout", outCircle)                   
                             .attr('class', 'node')
                             .attr('cursor', 'pointer')                                 
                             .attr("transform", function (d) {
                                return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
                                   });
```

for the click event i need to expand and collapse to the Children node.for this scenario the click is not firing , but without drag and drop event click is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

d3's `drag()` behaviour intercepts click events, and measures how much the mouse has moved between the mouse button going down, and the mouse button going up. If the mouse pointer has moved a distance between the two events, then it prevents a `click` event from firing. So a very fast, light click on an object will generally work, but a heavier, slower one will not.

The distance for a click to be a click is zero pixels, but fortunately, you can change this with the [clickDistance function](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/master/README.md#drag_clickDistance). Try:

```
node.enter().append('g').call(d3.drag()
   .clickDistance(1)
   .on("start", [etc.]
```

And see how adjusting the value given (1 might do it, you may want more or less) works out for you.

Comment: Thanks for the information , I tried this one also its not working , finally i made the some little changes in the start ,drop event itself.now its working correctly.